# VS Code intellisense menu display

Tags: visual-studio-code

I stupidly messed around with my vs code settings and now the intellisense option list is condensed. Does anyone know the fix for this?

[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the

`Editor: Suggest Line Height`

`0` is the default in which case it uses the `Editor: Line Height` setting, so it could be either one that is your issue.

Comment: Hero! Thanks for your help...that was driving me mad.